# Reading text files, error using load MATLAB

Tags: matlab, text-files

I have a text file containing my data looking like this:

```
3,848E-05
3,848E-05
3,848E-05
3,848E-05
3,848E-05
3,848E-05
3,848E-05
3,848E-05
3,848E-05 
2,3088E-05
-0,00013468
```

I have tried using load and get an error telling me that the ASCII file must contain the same number of columns per lines.

```
fname1 = fullfile(path,'test1.txt');
emg1 = load(fname1);


Error using load
Number of columns on line 233 of ASCII file must
be the same as previous lines.
```

I've also tried using importdata and that couldn't deal with this kind of number format. Any ideas? I'm using MATLAB 2014a.

```
fname1 = fullfile(path,'test1.txt');
emg1 = importdata(fname1);
```

This is how the imported data looked like using importdata.

```
3   0.00848000000000000
3   0.00848000000000000
3   0.00848000000000000
3   0.00848000000000000
3   0.00848000000000000
3   0.00848000000000000
3   0.00848000000000000
3   0.00848000000000000
3   0.00848000000000000
2   0.0308800000000000
-1  0.00924000000000000
```

Comment: Please upload your code and associated errors in a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems due to the fact that the values in the file contains `,` (comma) instead of `.` (dot).

In this cse, you can

- read the input file as a text file (containing string)ù
- replace the `,` with `.`
- convert the string to number (double)

A possible solution could be:

```
% Open the input file
fp=fopen('d.txt','rt')
% Read the file as a text file
C=textscan(fp,'%s')
% Close the text file
fclose(fp)
% Convert the string to numbers
x=str2num(char(strrep(C{1}(:),',','.')))
```

Hope this helps.

Qapla'